# displaying 2 outputs as a 2 separate columns | bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have two outputs from 2 commands:

```
comm1=`ip a | grep ens | grep -v lo | cut -d' ' -f2`
```

output example:

```
>eth1
```

and command two

```
comm2=`ip a | grep inet| grep -v inet6 | grep -v 127 | cut -d' ' -f6`
```

output example:

```
 >123.156.789
  234.167.290
  148.193.198
  138.25.49
  142.137.154
  125.175.166
  246.173.7
  154.167.67
```

Desired output:

```
echo "$comm1 $comm2"
> eth1        123.156.789
              234.167.290
              148.193.198
              138.25.49
              142.137.154
              125.175.166
              246.173.7
              154.167.67
```

If that would be single line outputs, then column -t works just fine,

```
echo "$comm1 $comm2" | column -t
```

but in this case, when one of the columns is multi line,  it is not working..
Looking for an efficient solution

edited

Comment: Your desired output doesn't seem to include any multi-line strings.  Please edit your question to indicate what you want to happen to multi-line strings.

Comment: BTW, that kind of big nasty pipeline is typically a code smell. Just one `awk` invocation could do the work of *all* those `grep`s *and* the `cut`.

Comment: ...and frankly, there's no guarantee that the information at field 6 today will be at field 6 tomorrow, so the `cut` would be better replaced with something that actually **looks inside the string** and relies only on documented format guarantees. For instance, if you want the word after `addr`, match on it because it's the word after `addr`, not because it's the sixth word in the line.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy , I'm opened to suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command `paste` and [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) for this, e.g.:

```
  $ paste <(comm1) <(comm2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want the `paste` command.

```
$ seq 1 3 > a.txt
$ seq 5 10 > b.txt
$ paste a.txt b.txt
1       5
2       6
3       7
        8
        9
        10
```